# how to refresh data in my table after update drop down list?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

So i have a table where i display my data from my database and a drop down list, what i want is to update my table each time i update the drop down list, this is my action :

```
public function index()
{
    $userid = User::lists('id');//here i get the id's of all my users
    $username = User::lists('username');// here i put data to my drop down list
    $services = User::find()->service;//here my table that should be updated

    return View::make('services.index',array('services'=>$services,'username'=>$username));
}
```

**and this is my view :**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('user_id', 'User Name') }}
    {{ Form::select('user_id', $username , Input::old('user_id'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

// my table should be updated after update the drop down list
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>User ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
                    // ....
            </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($services as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->user_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
```

Comment: How do you update your drop down list? Via Javascript? Could you share the related code?

Comment: can you give more information about your database structure? to me this looks kind of messed up. You first fetch a list of IDs, but you only get the 'service' of the first user anyway? then you get all user names only that is wrong too, it should not be the basis for your select statement. This will probably mix your ids up (take a look at your generated html, the 'option' tags probably begin with value="0"

Comment: Ah I think I understand it now. Your table shows all services that are related to one user. In your drop down you have all the users. If you change the user you want to update the services accordingly? I guess you have a hasMany relation from User to Service?

Comment: i update my post i wish to be clear now :)

Comment: Seems like you want to filter the table based on values on select box both on load and on change. Am I right?